# for loop with multiple conditions not working (JS)

Tags: javascript, for-loop, multiple-conditions

I'm trying to make this loop work in order to get the multiples of 5 that are below 1000 in an array (yeah, just getting started with euler), but it keeps crashing my console:

```
var multiploCincoArray = []; 

for(i = 1, r = i * 5; r < 1000; i++) {
    multiploCincoArray.push(r);
}
console.log(multiploCincoArray);
```

I know there's something wrong with the stopping condition but i can't seem to find it.

I know i can do this too:

```
var multiploCincoArray = []; 

for(i = 1; i <= 199 ; i++) { 
    multiploCincoArray.push(5 * i);
}
console.log(multiploCincoArray);
```

but i want to follow the path shown in the first script (if possible)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could move the calculation into the conditional part.

```js
var multiploCincoArray = [];
for (var i = 1, r; r = i * 5, r < 1000; i++) {
    multiploCincoArray.push(r);
}

console.log(multiploCincoArray);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try that :

```
var multiploCincoArray = []; 

for(i = 5; i <= 1000; i = i + 5) { 

    multiploCincoArray.push(i);
}
console.log(multiploCincoArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 for(i = 1, r = i * 5; r < 1000; i++){
```

Is the same as:

```
 i = 1, r = i * 5

 while(r < 1000) i++;
```

So actually you set `r` just once (to 5), then you increase `i` as long as `r` is smaller than 1000, but as `r` doesn't change the loop is infinite and crashes your browser.

You might just do:

```
 for(let i = 5; i < 1000; i += 5)
```

Comment: thanks a lot, i couldn't see why `r` wasn't changing!.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach doesn't seem right imo.

Firstly start with a single variable `i`, and iterate till 1000.

```
for (var i=1; i<1000; i++)
```

check if the i is a multiple of 5 via `i%5`, if it is then push the value in an array.

```js
var array = [];

for (var i=1; i<1000; i++) {
  if (i%5 === 0) {
    array.push(i);
  }
}

console.log(array);
```

Comment: This will be five times slower than the approach the OP is trying (if it would be fixed)

Comment: Just showing how to approach the question, you don't even need the loop to test values, you can simply start with the min possible multiplier and keep adding the multiplier. @JonasWilms

Answer (score 0):

On the right track but condition in the wrong place.  Change `for(i = 1, r = i * 5; r < 1000; i++)` to `for(i = 1, r=5; r < 1000; r=i*5,i++)`

Should use `let i` and `let r` for scope but I left it out for clarity.